# How many styles of element separators has LEGO produced?

Tags: piece-information

I used to use other LEGO elements to separate tightly bound pieces in my collection. My thumb nail and I were quite pleased when I first discovered an actual brick separator LEGO introduced to ease the task. How many styles of LEGO element separators has LEGO made available to the general public?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Bricklink lists two:

[OLD](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=6007) (in two colors):

[image]

[NEW](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=96874) (in three colors):

[image]

There is one other 'separator', but it doesn't look like it's very good for bricks: [RC Car Separator Tool - Metal](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=x1220)

[image]

ETA: The [Clickits Separator](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=clikits021a#T=C)!

[image]

---

As of 2020 there is [another brick separator](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=55819#T=C&C=11) designed for removing more tiles with a single motion and included with the Mosaic sets.

[image]

The DOTS theme added another implement in [two](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=78169#T=C) different [styles](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=69871#T=C) to remove individual tiles.

[image]

Comment: There's also the spanner (http://www.brickset.com/parts/?part=400626) which is used for removing tiles from dice in LEGO games.

Comment: Fair enough. Some games include the Crowbar instead: http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=92585